# How to nest multiple stages within a stage with a "when" clause

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to accomplish the following but getting the following error: **Unknown stage section "stage".**

I have a few stages that I am trying to nest under one stage with a when block to build/deploy on a certain branch. I tried using **stages** as the parent but got another error since I already have a stages stage somewhere else in the file. How do I accomplish this?

```
stage("Build and deploy") {
  when{branch "feature branch"}
  stage("Dev"){
  
  }
  stage("Test"){
  
  }
  stage("Prod"){
  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a self-contained pipeline that works for me:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('doing something') {
            when { expression { 2 > 1 } } // "branch" should work too
            stages {
                stage ('a') {
                    steps {
                        script {echo "a"}
                    }
                }
                stage ('b') {
                    steps {
                        script {echo "b"}
                    }
                }
                stage ('c') {
                    steps {
                        script {echo "c"}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
[image: BlueOcean]

Comment: When I tried that, I got the following error:

**Undefined section "stage"** for the "Build and deploy" stage, any ideas why?

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: where is this view that shows the output visualization like you have it? will it show say another build that is kicked of by a or b with 'wait: false'?